# Using Tensorflow/keras with Python multiprocessing pool

Tags: tensorflow, multiprocessing

I want to do a neural network training in Tensorflow/Keras but prefer to use python multiprocessing module to maximize use of system resources and save time. What I do is simply like this (I want to run this code on a system without GPU or with one or more GPUs):

```
import ... (required modules)
from multiprocessing import Pool
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
tf.keras.backend.set_session(sess)

... some tf and non-tf variable initializations...
... some functions to facilitate reading tensorflow datasets in TFRecord format...
... function defining keras model...

# Main worker function
def doWork(args):
    from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
    from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

    train_data = read_datasets(...)
    val_data = read_datasets(...)
    test_data = read_datasets(...)

    if (NumGPUs > 1):
        strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
        with strategy.scope():
            model = keras_model(...)
            model.compile(...)
    else:
        model = keras_model(...)
        model.compile(...)

    model.fit(train_data, epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=train_steps, ...)
    _, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_data, steps=test_steps)
    ...log results...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    a1 = <set of parameters for the first run>
    a1 = <set of parameters for the second run>
    pool.map(doWork, (a1, a2))
```

I can run this code on different computers and get my results, but some times I face system hangups (especially if I want to abort execution by pressing CTRL+C) or program termination with different errors, and I guess the above is not the right style of combining Tensorflow/Keras and Python multiprocessing. What is the correct style of writing the above code?

Comment: i think it's already optimized to use as much cpu as is available